# apache not resolving root domain in virtual host

Tags: apache

Reading http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html there is a part where it says:

```
If no matching ServerName or ServerAlias is found in the set of virtual hosts containing the most specific matching IP address and port combination, then the first listed virtual host that matches that will be used.
```

I have a vhost file with many virtualhost domains. The problem is that when I type my server IP I should go to root but no, I am being taken to the first listed virtual host AS THE apache documentation says.

SO how do I prevent that? How do I prevent that typing my server IP the user will be taken to the first virtualhost rule in my vhost file?

Comment: Where do you want to be taken, instead?

Comment: I want to be taken to my root public_html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. Once you start defining virtual hosts it will always be a virtual hosts which generate the response not the "outer default" documentroot.

So just create a new virtual host at the top of your virtual hosts list(So it will be the default virtual host), and then set its documentroot to what you want the default documentroot to be.

Answer (score 0):

Your first item should usually be localhost and resolve to that root ... –  Feras 19 secs ago   edit. That is the first vhost entry should be named and the server should be localhost.

Comment: but if I open the website with the IP? creating the virtualhost to localhost will work?